# no module named 'Pil' while using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, anaconda

I am totally new to Machine learning. I was using [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) for machine learning. While, i was following [code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/#4) for this. And i was compressing my model and testing it using following script

```
python -m scripts.evaluate  tf_files/optimized_graph.pb
```

i got this exception `no module name 'Pil'`
below is screenshot.

[image]

when i tried installing pip using this command `pip install Pillow`. I got this exception.

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\pip\ba
and.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\pip\co
\install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\pip\wh
", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\pip\re
set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\pip\re
set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\pip\re
install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\pip\in
", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\pip\in
", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\pip\in
", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\pip\in
", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\pip\in
", line 811, in get_page
    inst = cls(resp.content, resp.url, resp.headers)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\pip\in
", line 731, in __init__
    namespaceHTMLElements=False,
TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transport_encoding'
```

I am new to this and don't know whats going wrong

*UPDATED*

as suggested from Bodhi94 in answer bellow i replaced my html5 with the git file given in link and successfully installed `pip install Pillow` but when i run `python -m scripts.evaluate  tf_files/optimized_graph.pb` command again it gave me this exception.

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\runpy.py", line 193, 
in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
 File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in 
_run_code   exec(code, run_globals)
 File "D:\tensorflow\tensorflow-for-poets-2\scripts\evaluate.py", line 91, in <module>
accuracy,xent = evaluate_graph(*sys.argv[1:])
 File "D:\tensorflow\tensorflow-for-poets-2\scripts\evaluate.py", line 37, in evaluate_graph
 image_buffer_input = graph.get_tensor_by_name('input:0')
 File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2880, in get_tensor_by_name
 return self.as_graph_element(name, allow_tensor=True, allow_operation=False)

 File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2708, in as_graph_element
return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2750, in _as_graph_element_locked
"graph." % (repr(name), repr(op_name)))
KeyError: "The name 'input:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'input', does not exist in the graph."
```

Comment: `pip install Pillow`

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code / errors. This should be in a code block

Comment: @Sraw i did `pip install Pillow` this gave me exception you can see i have updated my question

Answer (score 3):

Try to install **html5lib** library using the following command

```
conda install --force html5lib
```

They try to install pillow using

```
pip install Pillow
```

Comment: If  `conda install --force html5lib` not work try to replace C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow2\Lib\site-packages\html5lib with the files from https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python/tree/master/html5lib

Comment: i did replaced files from git and successfully installed `pip install Pillow` but it gave me new exceptions please see i have updated my qestion

Comment: I think solution to this github issue might help you. https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet/issues/279